# How can I print the file names ending with .cif in a directory?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a directory with a lot of .cif files. I want to read through the file names and print the ones ending with .cif to a file.

Here is what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

directory=/MOFS

:>| names_mofs

myfilenames="${directory}/*.cif"
for file in $myfilenames
do
   echo $file >> names_mofs

done
```

But this code prints `/MOFS/*.cif` into the names_mofs file. I also need to print the whole name, including the .cif extension.

What should I do?

Comment: `:>|` I like how happy that looks, by I think you meant to just `> names_mofs`

Comment: I am using it because creates the file if it does not exist

Comment: There is no need to create the file first. Just move the redirection after the `done`; this also avoids closing, reopening and seeking to the end of the output file each time you iterate.

Comment: @tripleee like  this? `done ${names_mofs}`

Comment: Er, no, that's not at all what it looks like. My answer has an example. `done >names_mofs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't generally advocate using `cd` in scripts but here, it's by far the easiest way to get rid of the directory name.

```
( cd /MOFS; printf '%s\n' *.cif ) >names_mofs
```

The parentheses create a subshell, so the `cd` doesn't affect the rest of the script outside the parentheses.

If for some reason you want to keep the loop and avoid the `cd`, the `basename` command does what you ask. However, the shell can do pretty much the same thing with a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
for file in "$directory"/*.cif; do
    #basename "$file"  # notice proper quoting
    echo "${file##*/}"
done >names_mofs
```

In brief, `${variable##pattern}` produces the value of `variable`  with any prefix which matches `pattern` removed.

See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score -1):

```
ls -A "$directory" | grep -E '.*\.cif'
```

That should do it

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the info